# Infinite sequence of bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider and Infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials with probability of success equals to p. For a given number k let X denote the number of trial in which k-th success appeared. Find a distribution of X.
How to find that? The answer i have is ${{i-1}\choose{k-1}}p^k(1-p)^{i-k} $, but i have no idea where does this comes from.

Comment: Hint;  if the $k^{th}$ win occurs on trial $\# i$ then amongst the previous $i-1$ trials we need exactly $k-1$ wins. The probability just comes from thinking about how many ways we could choose those $k-1$ wins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The k'th success occurs at the i'th trial exactly when there is k-1 successes in the first i-1 trials, $B(i-1,p) = k-1$, and the i'th trial is a success.
$$P(X=i) = p \cdot P(B(i-1,p)=k-1) = p \left(\begin{matrix}i-1\\k-1\end{matrix}\right)p^{k-1}(1-p)^{i-k}$$